# What are these AWS CloudFormation built-in variable references called?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

They are not Pseudo Parameters, but what are they? Cannot locate any documentation on them.

Referring to anything with the syntax `${aws:SOMEAWSOBJECT}`. Trying to figure out their referencing.

```
                              "append_dimensions": {
                                      "AutoScalingGroupName": "${aws:AutoScalingGroupName}",
                                      "ImageId": "${aws:ImageId}",
                                      "InstanceId": "${aws:InstanceId}",
                                      "InstanceType": "${aws:InstanceType}"
```

Comment: These don't seem native to CloudFormation. Are you using another tool as well (e.g., Serverless, Terraform, etc.)?

Comment: Check here please: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/blob/master/aws/solutions/AmazonCloudWatchAgent/inline/windows.template. Some time ago I learned about them in aws user guide docs, but I am unable to locate that document. I am using them in a Cfn template, similar to how it is being used in the awslabs link I provided above. But in that sample, he has an exclamation mark, which seems incorrect since that will make ${} a literal when using it with Fn::Sub.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These properties are not native to CloudFormation itself, but are part of the [CloudWatch agent configuration file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html#CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Metricssection). You can use CloudFormation to create an agent configuration file though (as shown in your comment to the question), in which case these variables do show up in the CloudFormation file.

Comment: For anyone else with a similar inquiry, I found the document that refers to what these variable references actually are. They are IAM principals global condition context keys: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html

Comment: IAM policy condition keys also start with `aws:` but not all placeholders starting with `aws:` are IAM global context keys. The ones you refer to in the question are not, for example. They are for EC2/Cloudwatch. Notice how they do not appear in the documentation you linked in this comment. Rather, there are separate concepts for separate services that have the same `aws:`pattern.